# How to get object which is animated in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

### Question:

- **How to get object which is animated in Kivy?**
- **Is it possibe to get the object which is animated?**

---

### Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenOne, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.img1 = Image(source="F:\PyCharm Python Works\Kivy Test\opencityicon (1).png")
        box_layout = BoxLayout()
        self.add_widget(box_layout)
        box_layout.add_widget(self.img1)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        animation = Animation(d=1, x=560)
        animation.start(self.img1)
        print(animation.animated_properties)


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(ScreenOne(name='screen_one'))
sm.current = 'screen_one'


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

I am not able find a answer for my question in the docs of Kivy!

---

#### Thank you for reading!!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that currently. But you could subclass `Animation`, and have your new class keep a reference to the animated object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a customized version of the `Animation`, `Sequence`, and `Parallel` classes and a simple test case:

```
from kivy.animation import Animation, Sequence, Parallel
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MySequence(Sequence):
    widgets = ListProperty([])

    def start(self, widget):
        super(MySequence, self).start(widget)
        self.widgets.append(widget)

    def __add__(self, animation):
        return MySequence(self, animation)

    def __and__(self, animation):
        return MyParallel(self, animation)

class MyParallel(Parallel):
    widgets = ListProperty([])

    def start(self, widget):
        super(MyParallel, self).start(widget)
        self.widgets.append(widget)

    def __add__(self, animation):
        return MySequence(self, animation)

    def __and__(self, animation):
        return MyParallel(self, animation)

class MyAnim(Animation):
    widgets = ListProperty([])

    def start(self, widget):
        super(MyAnim, self).start(widget)
        self.widgets.append(widget)

    def __add__(self, animation):
        return MySequence(self, animation)

    def __and__(self, animation):
        return MyParallel(self, animation)


class TestApp(App):
    def animate(self, instance):
        self.animation = MyAnim(pos=(200, 200), d=5)
        self.animation.on_complete = self.completed

        # sequential
        # self.animation += MyAnim(pos=(400, 400), t='out_sine')

        # parallel
        self.animation &= MyAnim(size=(200, 300), d=5)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.another_anim, 1)

        self.animation.start(instance)

    def another_anim(self, dt):
        self.animation.start(self.label)

    def completed(self, widget):
        print('Animation completed - animated Widget:', widget)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.check_anim, 2)

    def check_anim(self, dt):
        print(dt, 'seconds after Animation completed - animated Widgets:', self.animation.widgets)

    def build(self):
        fl = FloatLayout()
        button = Button(size_hint=(None, None), size=(100,50), pos=(0,0), text='click here', on_press=self.animate)
        fl.add_widget(button)
        self.label = Label(text='label', size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 500), pos=(400, 200))
        fl.add_widget(self.label)
        return fl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

If you use this in place of `Animation`, then you can access the `widgets` list of animated `Widgets`.

Comment: Will this work with sequential and parallel animation?

Comment: Not as I originally posted. Sequential and parallel animation use the `Sequence` and `Parallel` classes (which extend `Animation`). If I could get them to extend `MyAnim` instead, it would work. Since I can't figure out how to do that, I have posted added code to my answer above that creates two new classes `MySequence` and `MyParallel`. I believe with those additional classes, and two new  overridden methods in `MyAdmin`, you can now access the animated `Widget` as described.

Comment: Can you please post an example? It is not working for me! @John Anderson

Comment: I have modified my answer in two ways. I have added a simple test case, and I have removed the override of the `stop` methods, so that the list of animated widgets can only grow. Every time the same instance of `MyAnim` (or `MyParallel` or `MySequence`) is used to `start` an animation, the animated widget is added to the list, and that list continues to be available after the animation completes.

Comment: What I mean is it says that there no property as widgets when I tried to use it. @John Anderson

Comment: Use `widgets` instead of `widget`. And use the updated code in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210002/discussion-between-sairam-kumar-and-john-anderson).

Comment: The `MySeqence` and `MyParallel` also needed `__and__()` and `__add__()` overrides. See updated answer.

Comment: Updated your answer to add `stop` and `animated widigets` **list property**. @John Anderson